# How to display data in spinner from json

Tags: android, json, spinner, android-spinner

I am retrieving values from a json url and then storing it in a string variable. Now I want to display that value in a spinner. I have created an array list in my strings.xml file. The xml file contains following code:

```
<string name="credit_card_title">Card Type</string>
<string-array name="credit_card">
<item >Select</item>
<item >Visa</item>
<item >MC</item>
<item >Amex</item>
<item >Discover</item>
```

my spinner code is:

```
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/crdtcrd_crdtype"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:entries="@array/credit_card"
android:prompt="@string/credit_card_title" />
```

After retriving the value from the json url I am storing it in variable name `String cardtype`

Now how can I display the value of `cardtype` in the Spinner `crtdcrd_crdtype`....

the json url is:

http://mygogolfteetime.com/iphone/login/ramu@gmail.com/123456

From this URL I have to retrieve the value of `cardtype` and after retrieving the value i have to display it in the spinner..

There are different values for `cardype` like `visa, mc, amex and discover`
All these values are in my `strings.xml` file and after retrieving the value I have to display it in Spinner..

Need Help still not able to find the solution..

I am trying to display the value of `cardtype` using the following code:

```
crdtcrd_crdtype.setSelection(cardtype);
```

But its showing a number of errors..
1. Change to setSelected(..)
2. Change type of cardtype to int

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score -1):

Please find the sample code below :

layout file : main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/cmbNames"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

layout : spinner_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Code : MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final String NAME = "name";

//{"name":["abc","pqr","xyz"]}
private String jsonNames = "{\"" + NAME + "\":"
        + "[\"abc\",\"pqr\",\"xyz\"]}";
private SimpleAdapter adapter;
private Spinner cmbNames;
private List<HashMap<String, String>> lstNames;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    populateSpinner(jsonNames);

    cmbNames = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.cmbNames);
    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, lstNames, R.layout.spinner_item,
            new String[] { NAME }, new int[] { R.id.tvName });
    cmbNames.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void populateSpinner(String jsonString) {
    lstNames = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonNames);
        JSONArray jArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray(NAME);
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            addNewName(jArray.getString(i));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void addNewName(String name) {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put(NAME, name);
    lstNames.add(map);
}

}
```